# .net chart controls - show values in mm:ss

Tags: c#, .net, controls, charts

I am plotting data on a .net chart control, and I want to display values on the x-axis in in minutes and seconds (mm:ss).  For example, instead of displaying 1.5, I would like the axis to show 1:30.  Any ideas?

Comment: what charting controls are you talking about? Microsoft? Manco? ..?

Comment: the .net 3.5 charting controls found here:  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried this using the Visiblox Silverlight charting API. It is possible with the following code:

```
<charts:Chart Name="chart">
    <charts:Chart.XAxis>
        <charts:DateTimeAxis LabelFormatString="mm:ss" />
    </charts:Chart.XAxis>
</charts:Chart>
```

You should be able to apply something similar to other charting controls.

Edit: Sorry, just notice that you are using the MS Charting library, the documentation does not mention a LabelFormatString but you should be able to set one in the style: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.labelstyle.aspx . You can use the Format property on the LabelStyle class here: system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.labelstyle.aspx